# How to use sample from WinBioCaptureSample to identify user?

Tags: winapi, window, biometrics

Currently i can capture biometric sample using **`WinBioCaptureSample`** and identify user using **`WinBioIdentify`**.

> This required two independent bio-metric device scan for getting sample and other for identification.

**How can i reuse same captured sample from WinBioCaptureSample()
to identify user?**

I have tried to use callback with both flags

- *WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE = for sampling*
- *WINBIO_PURPOSE_IDENTIFY = for identification*

  ```
  WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback(
     *sessionHandle,                // Open session handle
     WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE |  // Intended for sample
     WINBIO_PURPOSE_IDENTIFY,       // Intended for identifying user
     WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW,          // Sample format
     CaptureSampleCallback,         // Callback function
     NULL                           // Optional context
  );
  ```

**Source**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbiocapturesample#examples

Comment: You need to save the data to a database. Check my fingerprintf library - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1156801/FingerPrintf-A-small-library-for-quick-usage-of-th

Comment: Does `WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback` not work?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT yes **`WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback`** works, but it only provides sample and not the identification of user like **`WinBioIdentify`** do. I am looking to achieve this in single user scan.